# Get data from table1 where id1=id2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need some help with a script, [exemple here](http://2ads.pro/index.php)

They are 3 tables:

1. networks

   ```
   network_id  
   network_name  
   status
   ```
2. offers

   ```
   offer_id  
   offer_name  
   onetwork_id  
   status
   ```
3. list_ip

   ```
   network  
   offer
   ```

In index page at IP Adress Details, I get the Ids of Network and Offer Name,
----chose a network and an offer in select from, Add an IP sow can you see the results in IP Adress Details----
how can I get: network_name where the network (from list_ip) = network_id (from networks)
and
offer_name where the offer (from list_ip) = offer_id (from offers)

```
<?php                      

        $get_last = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT*FROM list_ip WHERE ip LIKE '".$ip."'");
        if (isset($_GET['remove']))
        {
            $remove =($_GET['remove']);

                {
                    // Remove the category
                    mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `list_ip` WHERE `id` = '$remove'");          
                }

        }
        while($l_ip = mysqli_fetch_array($get_last))
        {
    ?>  
    <tr>
        <td class="center" align="center"><img src="<?=$l_ip['flag'];?>" border="0"></td>
        <td class="center"><?=$l_ip['network'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?=$l_ip['offer'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?=$l_ip['ip'];?></td>
        <td class="center" style="border-right:1px #c0c0c0 solid"><?=$l_ip['date'];?></td>
        <td class="center">
        <a href="index.php?remove=<?=$l_ip['id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button></a>
        </td>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm a newbie , can you help me with my code not others questions and posts

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use join statements in your query.

Here is the query for your question:

```
SELECT *
FROM list_ip
INNER JOIN networks ON networks.network_id=list_ip.network AND
INNER JOIN offers ON offers.offer_id=list_ip.offer;
```

Fro your reference : [SQL Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)